# Jmeter giving dos in response instead of loading original page

Tags: windows, performance, jmeter, load-testing, jmeter-3.2

"Why" and "When" we get this code in JMeter response instead of the real/original page and how to get rid of it?

Script is running successfully but getting this in response & this appears randomly.

Code which i get in response against my request is as displayed in this screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In View Results Tree the default is showing the response as text file.

> The default Text view shows all of the text contained in the response.

You want it to render as Html so choose in drop down of component as HTML or HTML (download resources) and JMeter will render it similar to browser

> If the HTML (download resources) view option is selected, the renderer may download images, style-sheets, etc.